# How to populate custom React component in Keystone Admin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express, keystonejs

We're using Keystone (version 4.0.0-beta.8) as our Node.js CMS for the first time for a project and we're really liking it. However we're running into a vital missing feature of the CMS and that is adding **custom components** to the admin views.

What we would like to achieve is to add a custom React component to one of the **Keystone admin screens** and populate it with data from a [field watch function](http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fields-watching)

This component should only be visible for one of the list models. Right now, the only way to do this, is to edit one of the core files:

```
/node_modules/keystone/admin/client/App/screens/Item/index.js
```

and add some conditional rendering around it:

```
{(this.props.params.listId === 'my-list-model') ? (
    <MyComponent>{this.props.params.listId}</MyComponent>
) : null }
```

This works, but is not ideal off-course since you're overwriting core files. But I could overcome this short-come if I knew how I can feed this custom component with data from the Keystone list model declaration:

In: **/server/models/MyListModel.js**

```
import keystone from 'keystone';
import { someFunction } from './myFunctions';

var MyListModel = new keystone.List('MyListModel', {
   map: { name: 'title' },
});

MyListModel.add({
   title: { type: String, required: true },
   data: { type: Types.Code, language: 'json', watch: 'title', value: watchTitle, noedit: true },
});

MyListModel.register();


function watchTitle(callback) {
    if (this.title) {
        function cb(error, result) {
            if (result) {
                // Send result to React Component in Admin screen
            }
            callback(error, result);
        }
        someFunction(this.title, cb);
    } else {
        callback(null, '');
    }
}
```

Does anyone bump into the same issue or have any clue how to send data to a custom component in the react admin view of Keystone?

Thanks a lot!